# Reorder geom_bar() bars by count within a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(Gender = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                                      3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("Man", "Other", "Woman"), class = "factor"), 
                 Country = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L), levels = c("Germany", "Poland"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                   -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I use the below for loop to generate bar plots for each variable of `df`:

```
library(ggplot2)

for (i in colnames(df)){
  plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes_string(y = i)) +
    geom_bar()
  print(plot)
}
```

This works and generates 2 bar plots. That said, how do I reorder the bars in descending order?

Outside of a for-loop I use `reorder()`, or `fct_reorder()`, or `fct_infreq()` depending on data at hand. In some cases I also use the pipe to generate a `count` variable.

I've tried all of these in the for loop, but it doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

Happy to use either `geom_bar()` or `geom_col()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) instead of `aes_string()` (which has been deprecated since `ggplot2 3.0.0`):

```r
for (col in colnames(df)){
  plot <- ggplot(
        data = df, 
        aes(y = forcats::fct_infreq(
            !!sym(col))
        )
    ) +
    geom_bar()
  print(plot)
}
```

This works well with other tidyverse functions that you mentioned, like [`forcats::fct_infreq()`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_inorder.html) .

I also changed the name of the variable in the loop from `i` to `col`, because when I see `i` I expect it means an index.

Comment: SamR great. Say I wanted the inverse of fct_infreq(), how would I do?  Since I use horizontal bars, I actually need the inverse (smallest first). I can use fct_rev(fct_infreq()), or is there a better way?

Comment: I think that's a good way to do it in this case.